# Debug asp.net without Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is there any way I can debug asp.net application without Visual Studio. I mean I have all aspx and .cs files in the folder but the system doesn't have Visual Studion installed in it. Is there any way I can debug it via breakpoints?

Comment: What is the rationale behind wanting to do this?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain  one of my client has given me the support work for asp.net site and does not want to provide the visual studio for the next three months, not even express edition. I have no idea how would I debug the issues..

Comment: Weird...Can't you just download VS Express on your own?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain It's my customer machine, so I am not suppose to install anything without their permission.

Comment: @Chris, methinks you need some new clients ;)

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain +1 for the same thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to be easy but .net does have a command like debugger:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You would need to attach it to IIS or whichever process is hosting your site and I don't think it's easy to add the breakpoints, but it would do the trick.

However, the simpler option would probably be to get Visual Studio Express edition, it's free and does let you debug stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea if it's possible to create breakpoints and such without visual studio, but you could perform basic debugging by adding code to the existing files that outputs whatever you need (variable values, caught exception messages?) to a log file?